# How to print the abstract within the maketitle

Tags: titles, abstract

**Problem 1:** I want to use `\begin{abstract} abstract text here \end{abstract}` coding within  `\maketitle` command. But the abstract text is printed on separate page. How to avoid?

**Problem 2:**
I am using the `\firstpara{}` command and getting this output. I am manually given `\hfill\break \hspace*{12pt}` command. I will try to avoid this manual work. I want to use the environment code like `\begin{firstpara} text \end{firstpara}` without the manual commands. I don't know how to impllment the environement within the `\maketitle` command. Kindly advice.

If you run the MWE Noticed my problem.

MWE

```
     \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

    \usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

    \usepackage[%showframe,%
    a4paper,%
    paperwidth=8.27in,%
    paperheight=10.83in,%
    textwidth=7.018in,%
    textheight=9.08in,%
    twocolumn,%
    columnsep=13.7pt,%
    top=2.06cm,%
    bottom=2.35cm,%
    left=45.28pt,%
    right=45.28pt,%
    headheight=10.63pt,%
    headsep=26.25pt,%
    footskip=21pt,%
    ]{geometry}

    \makeatletter

    \newcommand\reviewerhead{\hfill\bf Reviewed by:}
    \newcommand\editedhead{\hfill\bf Edited by:}

    \let\@editor\@empty
    \newcommand{\editor}[1]{\protected@edef\@editor{\@editor #1\par}}

    \let\@reviewer\@empty
    \newcommand{\reviewer}[1]{\protected@edef\@reviewer{{\@reviewer
    #1}\par}}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \def\@metanote{}
    \def\metanote#1{%
         \gdef\@metanote{\hfill #1}}

    \newcommand\corhead{{\hfill\bf *Correspondence:}}

    \def\@correspauthoroverride{}
    \def\correspauthoroverride#1{%
         \gdef\@correspauthoroverride{\corhead\newline%
             #1}}

    \def\@presentaddressoverride{}
    \def\presentaddressoverride#1{%
         \gdef\@presentaddressoverride{{{\hfill\bf Present address:}}\newline%
            #1}}

    \def\@abstract{}
    \def\abstract#1{%
         \gdef\@abstract{ #1}}

    \def\@keywords{}
    \def\keywords#1{%
         \gdef\@keywords{\bf Keywords: #1}}

    \def\@firstpara{}
    \def\firstpara#1{%
         \gdef\@firstpara{#1}}

    \def\@maketitle{%
      \newpage
      \null
    \vbox to \textheight{
    \vbox to 656pt{\vfill%
        \hbox to 114.45pt{\hfill%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{114.45pt}%
        \begin{flushright}%
        \vspace{9.5pt}%
    {\editedhead\par}
        {\hfill\@editor\par}%
        \vskip 3.5pt%
    {\reviewerhead\par}
        {\hfill\@reviewer\par}%
        \vskip 3.5pt%
        {\@correspauthoroverride\par}%
        \vskip 3.5\p@%
        {\@presentaddressoverride\par}%
        \vskip 3.5\p@%
       {\@metanote\par}%
        \end{flushright}    
        \end{minipage}}}
    \hspace*{10.8pc}
    \vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-48.5pc}%
            \hbox to 375.49pt{\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{375.49pt} 
      \let \footnote \thanks
        {\raggedright\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont\@title\par}%
        \vskip 0.5em%
        {\large
          \lineskip .36em%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
            \@author%
          \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 0.45em%
        {\@abstract\par}
        \vskip 1em%
        {\@keywords\par}
        \vskip 1em%
        {\@firstpara\par}
       \end{minipage}}}}%
      \par
      \vskip 8.5em}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\reviewerhead}{\relax} 
    \title{Title}
    \author[1]{Auth A\/}
    \author[1]{Auth B\/}
    \author[1,2]{Auth C\/}
    \author[1,2]{Auth D\/}
    \author[3]{Auth e\/}
    \author[2]{Auth F\/}
    \affil{Sample Address Sample AddressSample AddressSample}
    \affil{Sample AddressSample AddressSample AddressSample }
    \affil{Sample AddressSample AddressSample AddressSample Address}
    \editor{Auth A, editor addresss editor addressseditor addressseditor addressseditor addresss}
    \reviewer{Auth B, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
   \reviewer{Auth C, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
  \reviewer{Auth D, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
 \correspauthoroverride{Cor author,\break cor address cor addresscor
 addresscor addresscor address\break e-mail:corad@uniroma2.it}
\presentaddressoverride{Pres author,\break pres address pres
addresspres addresspres addresspres addresspres address\break e-mail:
presauth@uniroma2.it}
\begin{abstract}
Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text 
\end{abstract}
    \keywords{Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text \vspace*{5pt}}
    \metanote{Emanuela Sgreccia and Hongying Hou have contributed equally to this work.}
    \firstpara{\section{Sec a}\label{sec1:001}
    Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para \hfill\break 
    \hspace*{12pt}Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample
    ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para\parfillskip0pt}
    \maketitle

    \noindent Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para.

Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para


    \end{document}
```

My Output and my problems below mentioned:
[image]

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean when you say that you want to use it 'within' the `\maketitle` command. Since that command does not take an argument, I'm not sure what you have in mind. Note that `\maketitle` starts a new page. So if you put this after the abstract, the title will be on a new page. If you want the abstract to follow the title, put it after the `\maketitle`.

Comment: Don't use `\def` when you can avoid it in LaTeX documents. Use `\newcommand` instead, as you get checking. For example, you are presumably overwriting the default abstract set up here. If you really want to do that, use `\renewenvironment`. Don't use `\bf` etc. Those command were deprecated 20+ years ago. Always use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` etc. in LaTeX documents.

Comment: If i am using this command "\begin{abstract} \end{abstract} after the \maketitle the content will be print on next page. This is not my required output. Currently i am using \abstract{} command to reach the required output. I don't know how implement the same output \begin{abstract} \end{abstract} coding.

Comment: I am design the article first page is stub column environment. So i should be use the code \begin{abstract} \end{abstract} to reach the required output. Kindly advice

Comment: If I compile your code as is, I get the abstract on the first page, and everything else on the second. I don't see how you can have the abstract typeset by `\maketitle` if you don't specify the abstract until after `\maketitle` is typeset? You could probably tell TeX that the left column has zero height or something and then typeset the abstract as part of a first page with a reduced width (using the package which changes margin sizes, for example).

Answer (score 1):

This at least gets it onto one page but that's all can really be said for it: it needs a lot of work. I got rid of some bad boxes but there are lots and lots. You should read the console output: `geometry` is not happy.

[image: one page, at least]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage[%showframe,%
a4paper,%
paperwidth=8.27in,%
paperheight=10.83in,%
textwidth=7.018in,%
textheight=9.08in,%
twocolumn,%
columnsep=13.7pt,%
top=2.06cm,%
bottom=2.35cm,%
left=45.28pt,%
right=45.28pt,%
headheight=10.63pt,%
headsep=26.25pt,%
footskip=21pt,%
]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\reviewerhead{\hfill\bfseries Reviewed by:}
\newcommand\editedhead{\hfill\bfseries Edited by:}

\let\@editor\@empty
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{\protected@edef\@editor{\@editor #1\par}}

\let\@reviewer\@empty
\newcommand{\reviewer}[1]{\protected@edef\@reviewer{{\@reviewer
      #1}\par}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\@metanote{}
\newcommand\metanote[1]{%
  \gdef\@metanote{\hfill #1}}

\newcommand\corhead{{\hfill\bfseries *Correspondence:}}

\def\@correspauthoroverride{}
\newcommand\correspauthoroverride[1]{%
  \gdef\@correspauthoroverride{\corhead\newline%
    #1}}

\def\@presentaddressoverride{}
\newcommand\presentaddressoverride[1]{%
  \gdef\@presentaddressoverride{{{\hfill\bfseries Present address:}}\newline%
    #1}}

\def\@abstract{}
\renewcommand\abstract[1]{%
  \gdef\@abstract{ #1}}

\def\@keywords{}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{%
  \gdef\@keywords{\bfseries Keywords: #1}}

\def\@firstpara{}
\newcommand\firstpara[1]{%
  \gdef\@firstpara{#1}}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
      \begin{minipage}[b]{114pt}%
        \vspace*{\fill}
          \begin{flushright}%
            \vspace{9.5pt}%
            {\editedhead\par}
            {\hfill\@editor\par}%
            \vskip 3.5pt%
            {\reviewerhead\par}
            {\hfill\@reviewer\par}%
            \vskip 3.5pt%
            {\@correspauthoroverride\par}%
            \vskip 3.5\p@%
            {\@presentaddressoverride\par}%
            \vskip 3.5\p@%
            {\@metanote\par}%
          \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}
  \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[b]{375.49pt}
          \let \footnote \thanks
          {\raggedright\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont\@title\par}%
          \vskip 0.5em%
          {\large
            \lineskip .36em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
              \@author%
            \end{tabular}\par}%
          \vskip 0.45em%
          {\@abstract\par}
          \vskip 1em%
          {\@keywords\par}
          \vskip 1em%
          {\@firstpara\par}
          \vfill
        \end{minipage}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em
\clearpage}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  %\renewcommand{\reviewerhead}{\relax}
  \title{Title}
  \author[1]{Auth A\/}
  \author[1]{Auth B\/}
  \author[1,2]{Auth C\/}
  \author[1,2]{Auth D\/}
  \author[3]{Auth e\/}
  \author[2]{Auth F\/}
  \affil{Sample Address Sample AddressSample AddressSample}
  \affil{Sample AddressSample AddressSample AddressSample }
  \affil{Sample AddressSample AddressSample AddressSample Address}
  \editor{Auth A, editor addresss editor addressseditor addressseditor addressseditor addresss}
  \reviewer{Auth B, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
  \reviewer{Auth C, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
  \reviewer{Auth D, Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss Review addresss }
  \correspauthoroverride{Cor author,\par cor address cor addresscor
    addresscor addresscor address\par e-mail:corad@uniroma2.it}
  \presentaddressoverride{Pres author,\par pres address pres
    addresspres addresspres addresspres addresspres address\par e-mail:
    presauth@uniroma2.it}
  \metanote{Emanuela Sgreccia and Hongying Hou have contributed equally to this work.}
  \keywords{Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text Sample Keyword text \vspace*{5pt}}
  \abstract{%
    Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text Sample abstract text}
  \firstpara{\section{Sec a}\label{sec1:001}
    Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para Sample Para

    \setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
    Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample
    ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para

  Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para.

  Sample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample ParaSample Para

}
  \maketitle



\end{document}
```